# How can I connect the cell like opposite way to the left cell?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to connect the cells, the left side one comes out exactly how I wanted, but the right side one looks weird...I want the right side one connects to the big one like opposite direction to the left side one......Can anyone help please??

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array,mathtools}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, positioning,backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (m2) [matrix of nodes,
         nodes={draw, minimum height=10mm, minimum width=8mm, 
         anchor=south},
         column sep=-\pgflinewidth, 
         row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
         nodes in empty cells,]
{
$10$ & $5$ \\
};

\matrix[below left of=m2, xshift=-0.3cm, yshift=-0.8cm] (m3) [matrix of         nodes,
         nodes={draw, minimum height=10mm, minimum width=8mm, 
         anchor=south},
         column sep=-\pgflinewidth, 
         row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
         nodes in empty cells,]
{
$10$ \\
};
\node[above of=m3,yshift=-2mm] (p2) {};
\draw (m2-1-1) |- (p2) -| (m3-1-1);

\matrix[below right of=m2, xshift=0.3cm, yshift=-0.8cm] (m4) [matrix of nodes,
         nodes={draw, minimum height=10mm, minimum width=8mm, 
         anchor=south},
         column sep=-\pgflinewidth, 
         row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
         nodes in empty cells,]
{
$5$ \\
};
\node[above of=m4,yshift=-2mm] (p3) {};
\node[above of=m4] (p4) {};
\draw (m2-1-2) |- (p3) -| (m4-1-1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you made nodes, they have dimensions and Ti*k*Z, by default, joins to the border. In this case, you really want a coordinate rather than a node. And you don't use `p4` at all.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, positioning,backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [my matrix/.style={matrix of nodes, nodes={draw, minimum height=10mm, minimum width=8mm, anchor=south}, column sep=-\pgflinewidth, row sep=-\pgflinewidth, nodes in empty cells}]
  \matrix (m2) [my matrix]
  {
    $10$ & $5$ \\
  };

  \matrix[below left of=m2, xshift=-0.3cm, yshift=-0.8cm] (m3) [my matrix]
  {
    $10$ \\
  };
  \coordinate [above of=m3,yshift=-2mm] (p2);
  \draw (m2-1-1) |- (p2) -| (m3-1-1);

  \matrix[below right of=m2, xshift=0.3cm, yshift=-0.8cm] (m4) [my matrix]
  {
    $5$ \\
  };
  \coordinate [above of=m4,yshift=-2mm] (p3);
  \draw (m2-1-2) |- (p3) -| (m4-1-1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: tidier joinings]

Note that the `above of` syntax is deprecated. You are loading `positioning`, but don't use its syntax. `above=<dim> of <wherever>` or `above=of <wherever>` is the recommended syntax now.

Comment: Can you give me an example of above=<dim> of <wherever>???

Comment: @user3390471 `above=5pt of m4`.